# Does anyone know the use cases for the trace_block method by Openethereum?

Tags: ethereum, nodes, go-ethereum

Does anyone know the use cases for the trace_block method by Openethereum?

Here's the link to it:

https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/trace-block

I cannot find any use cases listed for this method anywhere. Even in the official docs, it's not written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after my research, I came to know that:

The `trace_block` method is used to analyze the behavior of a blockchain.

For example, you can find the average `gasPrice` for a block by getting the traces of all the transactions in the block (traces contain the `gasPrice` for transactions). Then you can get the average `gasPrice` block by block and form a graph to visualize how the `gasPrice` has changed over time.

I found it in [this](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/what-is-trace_block) great article by Alchemy

Comment: Please, use link formatting: `[link](url)`

Comment: @SerjantArbuz Edited my answer to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

The trace_block method is used to trace the execution of a block. It returns a list of traces, one for each transaction in the block. Each trace contains information about the execution of the transaction, including the execution of each message call or contract creation operation.

```bash
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"trace_block","params":["0x1"],"id":1}' https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/your-api-key
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for answering my question but I also know what trace_block is, I was specifically asking about the use cases/applications for this method.

If you know of any use cases for it, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Get contract execution revert reason (including historical txs).
2. Gas usage per individual call action.
3. Byte-code ops, steps taken and gas used per OP code.

Maybe more, but there are the ones I know of.